# howto scroll a gtk.scrolledwindow object from python code

Tags: python, pygtk, subprocess, glade

I'm writing a python application that has a glade gui. Using subprocess to execute some shell commands in the background.

Using a glade GUI which has a scrolledwindow widget and a textview widget inside the scrolledwindow widget. The textview gets populated as the subprocess.Popen object run and display their stdout and stderr to this textview.

My problem is that the textview is constantly populated, but stays still @ scroll position 0, 0 (top-most, left-most)

I want this scrolledwindow widget to stays at bottom-most, left-most at all times...

Does anyone have any idea which method I need to call scroll this thing downwards?

Comment: I am going to go ahead and add this here because i spent 5 hours with the same problem and no solution worked. If you are adding the textview to scrolledwindow with add_with_viewport(textview), the solutions here will not work. Just use add(textview) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the horizontal and/or vertical gtk.Adjustment from the scrolledwindow, and change its values. See

- [get_vadjustment](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkscrolledwindow.html#method-gtkscrolledwindow--get-vadjustment)
- [gtk.Adjustment](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkadjustment.html)

The `set_all` method of gtk.Adjustment is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you are looking for.

http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq14.010.htp

Comment: this answer contains a broken link.

Answer (score 0):

look at `gtk.ScrolledWindow.set_placement`.

(never tried)

Comment: This only defines the position of the scrollbars in relation to the child window. Does not help in my case.